# How to visualize IMU data in Rviz

Tags: imu, rviz, ros-kinetic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm publishing `sensor_msgs.msg.Imu` messages with frame `imu` on topic `/imu/data_raw`, and I'm trying to view it in Rviz via `rviz_imu_plugin`. However, when I enable the plugin and set the topic, the console reports:

```
[ WARN] [1477283997.473557284]: MessageFilter [target=map ]: Dropped 100.00% of messages so far. Please turn the [ros.rviz_imu_plugin.message_notifier] rosconsole logger to DEBUG for more information.
```

and Rviz shows the plugin error:

```
Transform [sender=unknown_publisher]
For frame [imu]: Fixed Frame [map] does not exist
```

What do these mean? Obviously, something's not configured correctly, but these messages are unusably vague.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/246256/how-to-visualize-imu-data-in-rviz/) by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on ROS Answers with karma: 940 on 2016-10-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

RViz needs to know what the incoming messages are relative to, which in RViz is always called the *Fixed Frame*.

In this case you have your Fixed Frame set to `map`, but that isn't published by any authority in your node graph. So RViz complains that it cannot find the `map` frame. That in turn causes the entire visualisation of incoming data to fail, as the Fixed Frame is always at the root of all of RViz's transforms.

In this particular case, I'm guessing you only have a single node publishing your `sensor_msgs/Imu` msg. So to get RViz to succesfully visualise that data, you'll have to configure it to use your `imu` frame as the Fixed Frame.

> Obviously, something's not configured correctly, but these messages are unusably vague.

But it is one which has a lot of Q&As that turn up in a [search](https://www.google.nl/?gfe_rd=cr&gws_rd=ssl#q=rviz+fixed+frame+does+not+exist). And I'm sure I'm biased, but the error message does state what is actually wrong.

It would be nice if you could improve on the error message though: if you have an idea how to do that, I'm sure a PR would be accepted over at [ros-visualization/rviz](https://github.com/ros-visualization/rviz).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-24

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-10-24**:
When I changed my IMU messages to use "base_link", that fixed the error.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-24**:
That is also a possibility, provided that there is a known transform between `base_link` and `imu`.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-10-24**:
Also: I'd not recommend using `base_link` as the `frame_id` for a message from an IMU, unless the sensor is actually mounted on the `base_link` of your robot (and even that is questionable, as there will (almost) always be some kind of offset between the two).

**Comment by [Cerin](https://answers.ros.org/users/2186/cerin/) on 2016-10-24**:
Yes, in my case, the IMU is mounted on the base_link, but that's a good point about the offset, which there is.